# Moto G5 Plus- Facing issues with notification of whatsapp

Tags: notifications, motorola-moto-g5

Hello guys i have moto g5 plus (4gb 32gb version). It happen sometimes when there is notification of whatsapp , when i click on that notification it doesnot opens whatsapp .any other user facing this issue?

Comment: Try changing the notification permissions and setting it to highest priority (like in Marshmallow, don't know the equivalent in Nougat)

Comment: How that would help ? problem is when i click to notification it doesnot open whatsapp

Comment: I have Moto G4 plus with Android Nougat and I too get the same problem but very rarely. So I pass it.